# Listview flickers when I update it with a timer

Tags: c#

I would like to update some or all of my listview's items and subitems contents with a timer (1 second refresh) But the listview flicker each one second. Sometimes the subitems are lost during redrawing.  Because my listview contains data that is to be likely changed anytime, I use a timer.

Code:
I put this function in the timer's Tick method

```
void Refresh()
{
   foreach(string s in lsttring)
   {
      lv.items.add(s);
      lv.items[i].subitems.add(i);
   }
}
```

I expect only items content (item text and subitem text) that are changed will be changed not the whole listview along with the timer tick.

Comment: there are a lot of questions with good answers regarding how to update list view from an other thread, try search please

Answer (score 5):

The ListView control supports double buffering, it maps the DoubleBuffered property to the  native control's LVS_EX_DOUBLEBUFFER style flag.  It is quite effective but you can't get to it directly since it is a protected property.  Add a new class to your project and paste the code shown below.  Compile.  Drop the new control from the top of the toolbox onto your form, replacing the old one.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class BufferedListView : ListView {
    public BufferedListView() {
        this.DoubleBuffered = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
void Refresh()
{
   lv.BeginUpdate();
   foreach(string s in lsttring)
   {
      lv.items.add(s);
      lv.items[i].subitems.add(i);
   }
   lv.EndUpdate();
}
```

In this manner you update all the items and listview will be refreshed only at the end of this operation.
From [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.windows.forms.listview.beginupdate.aspx):

> ...if you want to add items one at a time using the Add method of the
>   ListView.ListViewItemCollection class, you can use the `BeginUpdate`
>   method to prevent the control from repainting the ListView every time
>   that an item is added. When you have completed the task of adding
>   items to the control, call the `EndUpdate` method to enable the ListView
>   to repaint. **This way of adding items can prevent flickered drawing** of
>   the ListView when lots of items are being added to the control.

Comment: Doesn't help, it still flickers on the EndUpdate call.

Comment: @HansPassant: is this because refresh rate is too high?

Comment: It just gets noticeable with frequent updates, 1 second is very visible.  Listview is a bit of a flicker bug since it tends to cram a lot of text in Details view.  That's why it has the LVS_EX_DOUBLEBUFFER style flag.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @HansPassant, I've learned something new!! I've just upvoted your solution, because it's simple and functional, great job! :)