# How do I efficiently and safely load file icons into a ListView in a worker thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

I'm struggling to work out the best way to load icons into a ListView (in `View.LargeIcon`) that's been initialised with a list of files.

I figured I was going to have to use an ImageList, so I created one and assigned it to the ListView. I created a BackgroundWorker to handle the gruntwork of loading the icon from each image.

1. In `DoWork` I used a combination of `InvokeRequired` and `Invoke` to add items to the ListView. This worked, but it caused the UI to flicker a bit and didn't seem particularly good. The inability to loop through `ListView.Items` from within the worker thread meant that a `List<ListViewItem>` had to be passed as the argument. I had trouble getting the BackgroundWorker to cancel even though I was calling `CancelAsync` and checking for `CancellationPending` in my loop and exiting if it was true. (Why exactly this occurred is not important at this point.)
2. I tried to use the `ProgressChanged` event to handle all the UI work. I called `ReportProgress(0, obj)` where `obj` was a custom class containing fields for the pieces of information I wanted the UI thread to use to update the UI (i.e., the ListView). This approach seemed more promising.

However, neither solution feels particularly elegant to me, and neither results in a particularly great user experience. I feel like I'm missing the (obvious) solution to this problem. After all, Windows Explorer handles loading thumbnails of images far better than my application does. I believe Windows Explorer caches thumbnails in Thumbs.db, though.

Perhaps one of the two approaches above *is* the right way to do it, and if this is the case please tell me, so I can investigate that particular solution in more detail to figure out what I'm doing wrong with it.

### Edit

I forgot to mention that the list of files and icons is being loaded from a network path.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Update listview's items and subitems with a timer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8378670/update-listviews-items-and-subitems-with-a-timer)

Comment: Or in other words: enable double-buffering.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend decoupling your business logic from your UI logic.  The code that loads the list of files and gets the icons for them should not be intermingled with code that works with the `ListView` control on the form.

For instance, I would recommend creating a class that simply contains all the data properties you need about each file:

```
class MyFileInfo
{
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public Image Icon { get; set; }
}
```

Then, write a method that returns a list of those objects already populated:

```
public List<MyFileInfo> LoadFileList(string folderPath) { }
```

Then, the UI can call that method on another thread, and when it gets back the results, it can then populate the `ListView` control from the data that was returned.  To stop the list from flickering while you are adding or modifying items, call the `SuspentLayout` method on the `ListView` control before you make any changes, and then call `ResumeLayout` when you are done making all your changes.

Comment: The thing is it takes milliseconds to load the list of files, but much longer to load the icons. I have the ListView prepopulated with the filenames, with no icon, and then I intended to load the icons, leaving the UI usable while the icons were loading. I could adapt your solution to store the icon only in MyFileInfo but then I can't populate the icons until I've got them all back, which could take up to 10 seconds. (It's doing all this over a network path, I neglected to mention.)